XML, XSD, XSLT simple template
I just need an XML, styled with a given XSD, to be presented in a browser. I have the following 3 files, all in the same directory (Windows, C:\test)
The 3 files are as follows:

data.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <table>
        <row>
            <column>John</column>
            <column>Doe</column>
            <column>30</column>
        </row>
        <row>
            <column>Jane</column>
            <column>Smith</column>
            <column>25</column>
        </row>
        <row>
            <column>Alice</column>
            <column>Johnson</column>
            <column>35</column>
        </row>
    </table>
</data>


data.xsd

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="data">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="table" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="row" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="column" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>


data.xslt

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>User Data</title>
                <style>
                    table {
                        border-collapse: collapse;
                        width: 100%;
                    }
                    th, td {
                        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
                        text-align: left;
                        padding: 8px;
                    }
                    th {
                        background-color: #f2f2f2;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h2>User Data</h2>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="data/table/row">
                        <tr>
                            <xsl:for-each select="column">
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Now, if I load the xml file into a browser, I dont see the table, but I get the following message, and see the file structure.
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<data>
<table>
<row>
<column>John</column>
<column>Doe</column>
<column>30</column>
</row>
<row>
<column>Jane</column>
<column>Smith</column>
<column>25</column>
</row>
<row>
<column>Alice</column>
<column>Johnson</column>
<column>35</column>
</row>
</table>
</data>

